# Reprojection of Grib2 files

Tags: qgis, gdal

Can I use gdalwarp function directly  for converting grib2 file from[0,360] t0 [180,180]?

I tried it

```
gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +pm=180dW' -t_srs EPSG:4326 gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000 gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50test_4326.f000 I got error
ERROR 1: Cannot guess driver for gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50test_4326.f000
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem, what is your question?

Comment: For fixing the error that is reported, define the desired outputformat with `-of`.

Comment: I need to change the projection  of grib file from EPSG::9122 to EPSG::4326( longitude range from [0,360] to [-180,180])